# Chart JS - This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided

Tags: chart.js, momentjs

I'm trying to get Chart JS to work with time axes, but I get this error in the browser:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.`

I installed "chart.js", "moment.js" and "chartjs-adapter-moment" with Yarn. After that I imported them in my js like so:

```
import moment from "moment";
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
```

In my chart options I did this:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'time'
    }
  }
}
```

But in the browser, I get this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.`

Comment: What version of ChartJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with Chart.js 4.3, chartjs-adapter-moment 1.0.1 and Node 20.

It works when I place/change the following lines in `node_modules\chartjs-adapter-moment\package.json`:

```
"type": "module",
"main": "dist/chartjs-adapter-moment.esm.js",
```