# Chart.js This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided. error with chartjs-adapter-date-fns included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, date-fns, react-chartjs-2

Chart.js time line graph does not render, and instead throws an error when x axis is set to `type: time` as is noted [in all the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.1.2/axes/cartesian/time.html), note that I'm using 4.1.2 and `react-chartjs-2`  wrapper around chart.js

```
import React from 'react';

import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  TimeScale,
} from 'chart.js';

import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend, TimeScale, CategoryScale);

export const Test = () => {
  const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
  const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
      },
    },
  };
  const dataset = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: labels.map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)),
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: labels.map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)),
        borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
      },
    ],
  };
  return <Line options={options} data={dataset} />;
};
```

However it *does* render when the options are changed to the following:

```
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    adapters: {
      type: 'time',
    },
  }
```

I can't find anywhere in the docs that it says to use the `adapters.time` option. Why does this work? How can I get it to work the way it does in the docs.

Comment: Typically, you would do `import 'chart.js/auto'` (to automatically register all Chart.js components) _or_ import and register them individually. (If you're willing to import and register them individually, that's better - it should allow tree shaking.) Try removing `import 'chart.js/auto'` to see if the double registration is messing up some Chart.js state.

Comment: @JoshKelley Thanks, but yes that line was actually a typo in the code sample. I verified it has been removed and still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know whether your project is using CommonJS (CJS) or ECMAScript modules (ESM)?

I'm wondering if you're running into the [dual package hazard](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/packages.html#dual-package-hazard) with Chart.js - it contains separate CJS and ESM versions, and it has global state (its registry of date/time adapters), and this registry does not appear to be shared between its CJS and ESM versions.

As a result, if your project is using the CJS version of Chart.js, while the adapter you're using is using the ESM version of Chart.js (or vice versa), things won't work.

chartjs-adapter-date-fns appears to be using the ESM version. (See [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/blob/v3.0.0/package.json).)

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75938554/25507) appears to be related (although it doesn't have a confirmed answer, so I'm not positive that that's what's going on),

Comment: This is almost certainly the issue. As an aside, an implementation detail, the chart.js component is being developed in a library/plugin component, and it works without issue. It only seems to fail when it is imported and referenced by the parent consuming application :/